# Mapping Expressions

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, automapper

I'm having a hard time mapping expressions for a `DataServiceQuery`.

My input is the following: `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate`
and `string entitySet`

I now need to convert that into `Expression<Func<TOutput, bool>> output`

I am currently using AutoMapper and have created a Map between `TEntity` and `TOutput` I then try map the Expression in the following way:

```
var type = Type.GetType($"ServiceContext.{entitySet}, ServiceContext");
var predicateTargetType = typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(bool)));
var mappedPredicate = _mapper.Map(predicate, predicate.GetType(), predicateTargetType);
```

The above code may seems as if it works, at runtime it executes however the problem is whenever I use the `mappedPredicate` variable it will throw the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Code supposed to be unreachable

The layer that calls this code knows nothing of `TOutput` so I only have the name of `TOutput` in string format and the Expression of `TEntity`.

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Check the [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/blob/master/README.md) and the tests in the repo.

Comment: @Lucian Thanks, I somehow missed this page, I ended up changing `_mapper.Map(...)` to  `_mapper.MapExpression(...)` and it worked! :p